# Why "Switch" doesn't work properly with comparison of two variables?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I wonder why the switch case is ignored, and the comparison of two variables doesn't even begin.
In Chrome debugger, the switch operation just is being skipped.

```js
let input = 5;

let generatedNum = 20;

switch(generatedNum) {
  case input === generatedNum:
    alert("The numbers match");
    break;
  case input < generatedNum:
    alert("Input is less");
    break;
  case input > generatedNum:
    alert("Input is bigger");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Because that's not how `switch` works...

Comment: *Technically* you could do `switch(true) { ... }` and keep your weird cases, and that would *work* but it'd be incredibly bad form.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Even in this case, it would only match the first expression that evaluates to `true`

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky Yes, I would hope that only one of `<`, `>` or `===` would be true at any given time :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `switch..case` construct is the following:

```
switch (variable) {
  case value1:
    block1
  case value2:
    block2
  case value3:
    block3
}
```

In your case, you want to use a simple `if..else` construct:

```js
let input = 5;

let generatedNum = 20;

if (input === generatedNum)
  alert("The numbers match");

else if (input < generatedNum)
  alert("Input is less");

else if (input > generatedNum) // technically, you can put just "else" here
  alert("Input is bigger");
```